# VBA - When I try to open different files I get a 400 error + do loop issue

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have will work for two specific files, but if I try to import any other data file I get a 400 error. So if I select "CRU01" or "CRU05" and then type "no" when it prompts for more data it works great. But if I try to import "CRU04" or any other datafile right from the start it doesn't even enter the loop and gives me the 400 error.

I'm also trying to increment a counter in a do loop so that each data file is pasted onto a different tab, but when I try this (I'll open CRU01 and then enter CRU05 when it prompts for more data) I get a "subscript out of range" message.

Code:

```
Sub ImportData()
    Dim FileLocation As String
    Dim finalRow As Long
    Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim Cycle As Variant
    Dim n As Integer

    Cycle = "yes"
    n = 0
    
    Do While Cycle = "yes"
        n = n + 1
    
        FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename
        If FileLocation = "False" Then
            Beep
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)        
    
        myValue = InputBox("Which unit is this? Use format CRUXX")
    
        'Find how many rows of data there are
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A100000").Select
        finalRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
        'MsgBox ("There are this many lines of data ->" & finalRow)    
    
        'import date and measured power
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C4:D" & finalRow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("A1")
    
        'set data type as column header (fan speed) and import fan speed data
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(9).Range("A3").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("C1")
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(9).Range("G5:G" & finalRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        'set data type as column header (theoretical W) and import data
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("G4").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("D1")
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("G5:G" & finalRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        'set data type as column header (supply air temp) and import  data
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(16).Range("A3").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("E1")
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(16).Range("D5:D" & finalRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        
    
        'set data type as column header (return air temp) and import  data
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(15).Range("A3").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("F1")
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(15).Range("D5:D" & finalRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        

        'set data type as column header (return air temp setpoint) and import  data
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("A3").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("G1")
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Range("D5:D" & finalRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues        
    
        'set data type as column header (humidity) and import  data
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(10).Range("A3").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("H1")
        ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(10).Range("D5:D" & finalRow).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Range("H2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        'set tab name to unit number and ask for more data
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n).Name = myValue
        Cycle = InputBox("Do you have more data? Enter Yes or No")  
  
        ImportWorkbook.Close
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: On what line do you get the `Application-defined or object-defined error`?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(n)Name = myValue` may result in multiple worksheets having the same name.

Comment: @TinMan I get that error when I used debug and get to this line: ImportWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A100000").Select. As for the naming question, how would I solve that? Giving each workbook a different variable?

Comment: Avoid selecting objects unless absolutely necessary.  The workbook is active but the `Worksheets(2)` will need to be selected.  I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Do all the worksheets have the same number of rows?

Comment: @TinMan No unfortunately it can vary

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a few helper functions to simplify the Import. But I could not test the whole system without sample data.  Changing the filename in `TestImport()`  and running it should tell you if it works.  If nothing else, I used a few advanced techniques that are worth studying if you don't know about them.

### Refactored Code

```
Option Explicit
Private Type FileInfo
    Index As Long
    UnitType As String
    FileName As String
End Type
    
Public Sub ImportData()
    Dim Files() As FileInfo
    LoadFiles Files
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(Files)
        With Files(n)
            ProcessWorkbook .FileName, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(.Index), .UnitType
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Sub TestImport()
    Dim Info As FileInfo
    With Info
        .FileName = "C:\Mock Data.xlsx"
        .Index = 1
        .UnitType = "CRUXX"
    End With
    
    ProcessWorkbook Info
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessWorkbook(FileName As String, ws As Worksheet, UnitType As String)
    Dim HeaderRow As Range
    Set HeaderRow = ws.Rows(1)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    'import date and measured power
    With wb.Worksheets(2)
        CopyData .Range("C4:D4"), HeaderRow.Range("A1")
    End With

    'set data type as column header (fan speed) and import fan speed data
    With wb.Worksheets(9)
        HeaderRow.Range("C1").Value = .Range("A3").Value
        CopyData .Range("G5"), HeaderRow.Range("C2")
    End With

    'set data type as column header (theoretical W) and import data
    With wb.Worksheets(2)
        HeaderRow.Range("D1").Value = .Range("G4").Value
        CopyData .Range("G5"), HeaderRow.Range("D2")
    End With

    'set data type as column header (supply air temp) and import  data
    With wb.Worksheets(16)
        HeaderRow.Range("E1").Value = .Range("G4").Value
        CopyData .Range("D5"), HeaderRow.Range("E2")
    End With
    
    'set data type as column header (return air temp) and import  data
    With wb.Worksheets(16)
        HeaderRow.Range("F1").Value = .Range("G4").Value
        CopyData .Range("D5"), HeaderRow.Range("F2")
    End With
    
    'set data type as column header (return air temp setpoint) and import  data
    With wb.Worksheets(16)
        HeaderRow.Range("G1").Value = .Range("G4").Value
        CopyData .Range("D5"), HeaderRow.Range("G2")
    End With
    
    'set data type as column header (humidity) and import  data
    With wb.Worksheets(16)
        HeaderRow.Range("H1").Value = .Range("G4").Value
        CopyData .Range("D5"), HeaderRow.Range("H2")
    End With
    
    'set tab name to unit number and ask for more data
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Name = UnitType
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Rem If the Unit Type has been used already
        Rem Add the Worksheets index to it's name
        ws.Name = UnitType & " " & ws.Index
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    wb.Close False
End Sub

Private Sub CopyData(Source As Range, Destination As Range)
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = DataCells(Source)
    
    Destination.Resize(UBound(Data), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
End Sub

Private Function DataCells(Source As Range) As Range
    Dim ColUsedRange As Range
    Dim Col As Range
    Dim RowCount As Long
    
    For Each Col In Source.Columns
        Set ColUsedRange = Range(Col, Col.EntireColumn.Cells(Source.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If RowCount < ColUsedRange.Rows.Count Then RowCount = ColUsedRange.Rows.Count
    Next
    
    Set DataCells = Source.Resize(RowCount)
End Function

Private Function LoadFiles(Files() As FileInfo)
    Dim Map As New Collection
    Dim n As Long
    Dim UnitType As Boolean
    Dim ExitFlag As Boolean
    ReDim Files(1 To 1000)
    
    n = 1
    Do
        With Files(n)
            .FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
        
            If .FileName = "False" Then
                .FileName = ""
                n = n - 1
                ExitFlag = True
            Else
                On Error Resume Next
                Map.Add .FileName
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    MsgBox .FileName & " has been selected already", vbInformation, ""
                    n = n - 1
                Else
                    .UnitType = InputBox(Prompt:="Which unit is this?", Default:="CRUXX", Title:="Unit Type")
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End With
        If ExitFlag Then Exit Do
        n = n + 1
    Loop Until Not MsgBox("Do you have more Data?", vbYesNo, "Continue") = vbYes
    If n = 0 Then
        ReDim Files(0)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve Files(1 To n)
    End If
End Function
```